# Probable template specialization within a class

Tags: c++

I encountered code like the following:

```
class XX
{
public:
    template<typename TT> struct YY;

    template<typename TT, typename UU> struct YY<std::pair<TT, UU>>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(std::pair<TT, UU> const& val) const
        {
            // content omitted for brevity
        }
    };
};
```

Basically, I am confused and need help in understanding this code.

Specifically, is the first YY declaration a forward declaration? Is the second YY declaration a partial template specialization? Why does the second YY declaration have two template arguments (TT and UU), while the first YY declaration only have one template argument (TT)? Why does the first YY declaration have no definition?

(The code compiles with no problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically, is the first YY declaration a forward declaration?

Yes. This renders any instantiation `YY<T>` an incomplete type except...

> Is the second YY declaration a partial template specialization?

... if there is a template specialization for a certain type or class of types (like pointers) that provides a full definition. In this particular case, this is indeed a partial specialization, applying for all `YY<T>` with `T` being a pair type with `TT` and `UU`.

> Why does the second YY declaration have two template arguments (TT and UU), while the first YY declaration only have one template argument (TT)?

The author of the code didn't want to impose any conditions on the pair's types, they shall be arbitrary. By writing such a specialization, you basically promote all `YY` instantiations taking a `std::pair` to be a template with two arguments.

> Why does the first YY declaration have no definition?

Because it may not be needed. All you need to create specializations is a declaration. If you actually defined `YY` there, you would have gotten a "default" instantiation that always gets instantiated when no specialization is apt. If you *want* the compilation to fail if you chose a type where there is no specialization, you can do it like that. Alternatively (and probably better), you actually would define the template, containing a `static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, T>)` or something like that together with a more meaningful message than something like "cannot create object of incomplete type".

Comment: But `static_assert(false)` makes the program ill-formed, so you have to rely on tricks to make the `false` dependent on the template arguments somehow :)

Comment: @Quentin True, but elaborating on this would bloat the answer too much. There are already too many questions here.